# A Technicality for an Arbitrary Cartesian Product Intersection Identity

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm going through Munkre's *Topology* book. To set the stage, we want to be able to define a cartesian product for arbitrary index sets.

He employs the following definition: Let $\{A_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of sets; let $X = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}A_{\alpha}$. The **cartesian product** of this indexed family, denoted by $\prod_{\alpha \in J}A_{\alpha}$ is defined to be the set of all J-tuples of elements of $X$. That is, the set of all functions
\begin{equation}
x: J \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}A_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
such that $x(\alpha) \in A_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in J$.

Alright, this is all well and good. My goal is to show the following identity: Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ and $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be two indexed family of sets. Then,
\begin{equation}
     \prod_{\alpha \in J}(U_{\alpha} \cap V_{\alpha}) = \prod_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha} \cap \prod_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
Going in one of these directions isn't difficult to do but I've been having trouble with the reverse direction due to a subtlety. I am having difficulty showing that $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in J}(U_{\alpha} \cap V_{\alpha})$ implies $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha} \cap \prod_{\alpha \in J} V_{\alpha}$.

I'll now walk through my attempt until the point where I got stuck:
Suppose that $f \in \prod_{\alpha \in J}(U_{\alpha} \cap V_{\alpha})$, then $f: J \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}(U_{\alpha} \cap V_{\alpha})$ such that $f(\alpha) \in U_{\alpha} \cap V_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in J$. Therefore, $f(\alpha) \in U_{\alpha}$ and $f(\alpha) \in V_{\alpha}$. Trivial so far, no issues. Our goal is to simultaneously show that we can write $f: J \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha}$ and $f: J \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}V_{\alpha}$. Here is where it gets nuanced for me. For us to be able to do this requires that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in J}V_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}(U_{\alpha} \cap V_{\alpha})$. Part of what defines a function is its codomain, so these sets must be equivalent for us to proceed with the result, but it seems like there is no reason why these sets should be equal. I will say that it's trivial to construct functions
\begin{equation}
     f': J \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}U_{\alpha}, \qquad f'': J \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}V_{\alpha}
\end{equation}
such that $f'(\alpha) = f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in J$ and $f''(\alpha) = f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in J$. However, $f \neq f' \neq f''$ because the codomains are all different. I was wondering whether I'm missing something or if the notion of a cartesian product requires an amendment, namely something like "...that it is the set of all surjective functions $x: J \to A$ such that $A \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}A_{\alpha}$ and $x_{\alpha} \in A_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in J$".

Comment: What matters more for the definition of the product: the codomain of the function $f$, or just the values that it takes? I would say the latter, which should solve your problem.

Comment: @William While I agree that it's more important, math is precisely the arena in which we should be pedantic. If I have a definition for some object, then I want to rigorously show the implications of that definition. In this case, part of my question is understanding whether a different notion of a cartesian product has been used for the proof. In fact, the direction that I'm trying to prove has an impact on whether we have a basis for the box topology. I have no problem adopting such a modified definition if that is actually what everyone is using but I want to ensure my proofs are rock solid

Answer (score 1):

We often consider functions in general topology as sets of tuples. In particular, co-domains aren't a property of a function in this context: e.g. the functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=g(x)=x^2$ are equal as sets so we say $f=g$.

Comment: In this context, I wouldn't consider it important but it's a technicality that I think can be easily addressed by slightly amending the definition of a cartesian product (at least given how functions were defined in this text). Broadly speaking, the codomain determines whether a function is surjective or not. In Munkre's Topology (the book that I was using), he emphasizes this point early on, so that the two functions you provided in your example would not be considered the same object.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your book has defined function and $f:A\rightarrow B$.

A common definition of function is:

A function is a binary relation which is single valued.

And a relation $R$ is single valued $\Leftrightarrow \forall z (\forall x(\forall y((<x,y> \in R \land <x,z> \in R)\rightarrow\ y=z))).$

And a common defintion of $f:A\rightarrow B$ is $f:A\rightarrow B\Leftrightarrow$ dom$ \ f=A,$ ran$ f\subseteq B$ and $f$ is a function.

Under this definition, if $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $B \subseteq C$ then $f:A\rightarrow C$.

In your example if we use these definitions, $f:J\rightarrow\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha \cap V_\alpha$ and as $U_\alpha\cap V_\alpha \subseteq U_\alpha, \bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha\cap V_\alpha\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha$ and $f:J\rightarrow\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}U_\alpha$ (and similarly for $V_\alpha$).

If the defintion you are using includes the codomain in the defintion of the function (e.g. it is a triple $<f,A,B>$) then the problem statement and\or defintion of cartesian product needs to be ammended appropriately.

You might also find that some books are a bit loose with the defintions, leading to theorems that don't always quite work out :).